# difference between cesium.load json and ajax get json

Tags: json, ajax, cesiumjs

my boss wanted to me to replace the Cesium.loadJson function with ajax get  json data. I am wondering why he want the ajax get function rather than the cesium.loadJson. Does ajax get has more benefit than Cesium.loadjson?? What is ajax get so superiror to cesium.loadjson. Can you please explain to me the difference between ajax get json data and cesium.loadjson???
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the "ajax get json" function you refer to is the [jQuery AJAX get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), let me know if that's not the case.

Cesium does not directly depend on jQuery, so internally, Cesium and its various samples always use the built-in [`Cesium.loadJson`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/loadJson.html) to fetch JSON data from the server, because it can't assume that jQuery will be available.

Stack Overflow isn't the right format for a side-by-side comparison of the relative merits of the different functions.  But, I can tell you that there's no harm to your code if you decide to replace `Cesium.loadJson` with jQuery's or any other means of obtaining data from the server.  Cesium isn't doing anything fancy under the hood with `loadJson`, it's just a promise-based wrapper around some underlying XHR functions.  So, if your boss wants it replaced, feel free.

Comment: Does ajax get json has benefit over cesium.loadjson in performance, reliability and speed??

Comment: ajax get json can allow to get data without the need of reloading page while cesium.loadjson cant do that

Comment: No, both of these functions just map to the browser's own XHR handling mechanism under the hood.  The web browser is making the request back to the server, not the JavaScript itself.  So I wouldn't expect any meaningful performance difference between different XHR wrapper functions.

Comment: And yes obviously both of them can get data from the server without reloading the page.